# Want to display all the List items Like a View through button click on Infopath Form

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a form which takes 2 different input forms within.

Scenario - On Button Click user is redirected to a View which contains 2 buttons and each button has different fields like filling up a form, problem is both the form filling is going into single list, now my problem is when i go into SP list it shows both in a single line item.

Can someone please help me how can I bifurcate this? Also my manager wants a button  within the infopath form where he clicks and he gets a view of all the new items. Is it even possible?

Thanks, Any suggestion would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

About that different buttons submit data into a single item, you need to check the submit button and check its submit actions.

About clicking a button to view all list items, yes, you can do that.

The below steps for your reference:
1. Create a data connection to the list that you want to show and remember to uncheck "**Automatically retrieve data when form is opened**".
[image]

2. Add a button and create a rule on it to query the data connection.
   [image]
3. Add a repeating table into your form and click "Change Binding" to binding the data connection to the table:
   [image]